# Display issue using inline-block in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css

Here is the problem: I tried to create a page by putting two "p" elements aligned on the same line using display: inline-block in the "p" and the last child with float: right. The code worked fine in Chrome but when I tried it in Edge I noticed a small problem: the footer is not at the bottom of the page as it should be, but creates an empty space of at least 1px.

Page view in Google Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfCkl.png

Page view in Microsoft Edge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFHz1.png

But if I change the background color of the body to the same as the footer the margin "disappears".

The problem is that I do not want to change the color of the body nor use position: absolute to put the footer down because I tried to fix it that way and it worked but I do not want to use that property. I do not know if it is an Edge display problem or if you guys could tell me if the code is wrong. Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <!-- content of the page -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="copyright">
                <p>Footer text</p>
                <p>More Footer text</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.wrapper, footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 90%;
}

footer {
    background-color: #333;
}

.copyright {
    padding: 20px;
}

.copyright p {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.copyright p:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.wrapper, footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 90%;
}

footer {
    background-color: #333;
}

.copyright {
    padding: 20px;
}

.copyright p {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.copyright p:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <!-- content of the page -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="copyright">
                <p>Footer text</p>
                <p>More Footer text</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Please add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.copyright p`

Comment: Simple but efficient! It now shows correctly on Chrome 60 and Edge 41.

Comment: If it works you may accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)